# Data migration from Azure Table Storage to Cosmos DB Table Storage,

Tags: azure, database-migration, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

Are there any tools from Azure or elsewhere to reliably transfer my azure table storage[not azure cosmos db table] over to the cosmos db (table)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate Cosmosdb from one account to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437442/how-to-migrate-cosmosdb-from-one-account-to-another)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: I published this small project [here](https://github.com/m-rom/azure-migrate)

Answer (score 2):

Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool-imports-from-azure-table-storage/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement a logic app to keep the table and the Cosmos DB instance in "sync" following an initial sync in Satchin's answer.